# check download progress

Tags: android

I m download by following way and its working fine.But want to check at which time each chunk is coming.

File file = new File(extStorageDirectory+"/"+runInBackend.count+sche.file_name);

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

   connection.setDoOutput(true);

   connection.setConnectTimeout(sche.TimeOut);

   connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

   String status = connection.getHeaderField(0);//getResponseMessage();

   if(status != null && status.contains("200"))

    {
            InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();

            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);

            ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);

            int current = 0;

            long totalBytesRead = 0;
                 while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) 

                 {
                     baf.append((byte) current);

                     totalBytesRead ++;

                 }
                 FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

                 fos.write(baf.toByteArray());

                 fos.close();
```

Is there any way to check download progress of any fie, that is at what time each chunk is coming.

plzz help...

Thanks

Comment: Try using progress dialog in front & run your code in background

Answer (score 0):

You should probably move the download into a background thread, for example, using [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

When you get the initial response, you can pull out the content-length header to keep track of how far you've got in the download. You can always get the current time with [System.currentTimeMillis](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29) or [Date](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html) if you want to generate an ETA.

Hope this helps,

Phil Lello

Comment: i m already doing AsyncTask actually i want to know at which  time a packet is coming

Comment: Then use System.currentTimeMillis or Date when the read returns. If you read multiple bytes at a time through is.read(byte[] buffer), performance will be much better, and buffering wont interfere with the time returned by new Date() or System.currentTimeMillis. You won't be able to get the time a packet was sent, only the local system time when it becomes available to you.